# r wordcloud external ttf vfont not recognized

Tags: r, truetype, word-cloud

I've installed the 'extrafont' package in order to install an external font library [Duality](http://www.allfreefonts.com/font-4170-duality.html) via the ttf_import() method. However, when specifying the font via the wordcloud method, I receive the following error:

Installation command:

```
# Assuming the font file, DUALITY_.ttf, is in the working directory (see link to font above)
font_import(".",FALSE,pattern="DUALITY")
```

Wordcloud command:

```
wordcloud(ap.d$word, ap.d$freq, scale=c(8,2), min.freq=10, vfont=c("Duality","plain"),
      random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=pal2, fixed.asp=FALSE)
```

Output:

```
Error in strwidth(words[i], cex = size[i], ...) : 
  invalid 'vfont' value [typeface -2147483648]
```

In order to verify that the font is indeed installed, I issued the following commands

```
> choose_font("Duality")
[1] "Duality"
> fonts()
....[49] "Waree"                    "Duality"
```

How come the Duality font is not visible to the vfont parameter of wordcloud? And how do I make it visible to Cairo (the default renderer). TIA!

Comment: I've had luck using `windowsFont` to load a font into R, and then using the `family` argument to `par` to allow base plots to use it.

Comment: Is that function case sensitive about font name?

Comment: I'll try the windowsFont although the default Cairo installation doesn't support win fonts =\

Answer (score 4):

I've been able to overcome the same problem using the parameters passed to text `family` and `font` and described in `?par` instead of `vfont`. Also I needed to load the font first. So the thing goes:

Import the font (sorry, the link to Duality provided in OP is no longer available, I use Lucida Handwriting instead, available in windows):

```
library(extrafont)
font_import(pattern="LHANDW")
```

Load (see this [blog](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html) for details):

```
loadfonts() # loadfonts(device = "win") if you are working in windows
```

Wordcloud:

```
wordcloud(ap.d$word, ap.d$freq, scale=c(8,2), min.freq=10, family="Lucida Handwriting", font=1,
  random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0, use.r.layout=FALSE, colors=pal2, fixed.asp=FALSE)
```

Comment: How do you know how to refer to the font?  The mapping between LHANDW and "Lucida Handwritng"?  Also, where can you see what _are_ the legal values of vfont().  Is that possible to look up?

Comment: @user1603472 What I did was check de name of the font file in my PC.
I work with windows, and as far as I know fonts are not in R but in your OS. so I looked for the font I wanted to use inf the "Fonts" folder, right clicked on the file for my font and get the DOS name of the file from General Tab, in my case LHANDW.TTF.
Regarding the second part of your question. You can use any font you have installed on your computer, and to know which ones are available you can just list the files on your "Fonts" directory.

Answer (score 1):

To complement previous answers, and explain how one can actually choose which fonts to use. First, import fonts (it is possible to set a path different from the default in `font_import()`

```
library(extrafont)
font_import(prompt = FALSE)
```

To know which fonts are available:

```
unique(fonttable()$FamilyName)
```

This presents the exact reference for what to include as "font family". You can then issue the `wordcloud` command like this:

```
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62), family = "Carlito", font = 1)
```

Why `font = 1`? From `?par()`, here's what it says about the `font` parameter:

> An integer which specifies which font to use for text. If possible,
>   device drivers arrange so that 1 corresponds to plain text (the
>   default), 2 to bold face, 3 to italic and 4 to bold italic.