# Change font in Wordcloud package R

Tags: r, word-cloud

The title is super self explanatory: I want to change the font (text type, bold) of the wordcloud package in R.

Comment: Also see this related SE question for TTF fonts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18108512/r-wordcloud-external-ttf-vfont-not-recognized

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `family` and `font` arguments:

```
library(wordcloud)
set.seed(1)
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62), family = "serif", font = 3) 
wordcloud(c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9), seq(1, 1000, len = 62), family = "mono", font = 2)
```

[image]

See `?par` under `font` and `family` for details. The `extrafont` package gives more options. You find many examples on SO.